# How To Add Animation Graphics To An Android Game

Tags: android, animation, graphics-programming, particles, android-studio

How to make something like this animation drawings that coming out from the car ?

(I'm using android studio)

The Game's Link : [Finger Driver](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ketchapp.fingerdriver)

[image]

Comment: This effect looks like something called a "Particle System" — I recommend searching on that term for more information & examples.

Answer (score 1):

As it has been already mentioned in the comments, this effect is called "[Particle System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_system)".

What it does, basically, is spawn multiple objects over a period of time, and each object has a small animation before it "dies". I haven't played the game on your screenshot, but from what I can tell, in this case, the particle system is attached on the car, and every so often spawns a circle with a specific size. Each circle spawned this way, keeps decreasing in size, until they reach 0 in which case they destroy themselves.

There is no "right" or "wrong" way to make something like that. You can either create a simple particle system yourself, or you can use a library which already includes a solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve this will be to use a sprite sheet and use Rect to show different areas of the sheet quickly (giving the illusion of movement/ animation). I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797605/how-to-draw-onto-canvas-leaving-a-trail-android) article will be of use to you.